# Commands not found in shell script

Tags: shell-script, path

I need to execute `scp` command without using `expect` command in script.

How to use scp with password? I have tried with following code.

```
HOST=lnx1
USERNAME=user
PASSWORD=pwd
PATH=/sample/data/
FILE=$1
scp $FILE $USERNAME:'$PASSWORD'@$HOST:$PATH       
sshpass -p '$PASSWORD' scp $FILE $USERNAME@:$PATH
```

Error messages:

```
scp: command not found
sshpass: command not found
```

How to achieve this thing?

Comment: Your script has only 12 lines and the error is on line 16.

Comment: And you should not append to your question, the first one is answered and solved. Make a new one for the second otherwise the answers make no sense for the question and or title changes, so please roll back to revision 2 of your question.

Comment: `user` should be your _actual_ user name.

Comment: @terdon if the "user" would be a problem, that would give a "permission denied, please try again"

Comment: @Anthon yes, but the error message suggests the OP is also using `user` instead of a real username. There is also presumably a syntax error somewhere but I can't find it from the information given.

Comment: I rolled back this question to its original version. Once you receive an answer that solves your initial problem, accept it and then post a new question to pursue it further. Editing the original one in this way renders the existing answers irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set your `PATH` variable to `/sample/data`. The previous contents of the `PATH` variable have been overwritten with this. As a result, your script looks in `/sample/data` for `scp` and `sshpass`, fails to find them there, and gives you the error messages that you are seeing.

Try changing the `PATH` variable name to a different name, e.g:

```
REMOTE_PATH=/sample/data/

scp $FILE $USERNAME:'$PASSWORD'@$HOST:$REMOTE_PATH

sshpass -p '$PASSWORD' scp $FILE $USERNAME@:$REMOTE_PATH
```

If that doesn't work, try putting the full path name to `scp` and `sshpass` in your script.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have updated the question. please look on it. Am getting "ssh: user: Name or service not known lost connection".